# JavaScript en WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, script, wordpress-theme, wordpress-plugin

Necesito insertar un script en una pagina de wordpress pero al momento de la ejecución no me muestra el script, no se si necesito agregarlo en el código base de la pagina de wordpress o agregar algún plugin

```
<script type='text/javascript'> width=640, height=480, channel='CanalCNC', g='1';</script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.liveflashplayer.org/resources/scripts/hliveFlashEmbed.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de hacerlo es editando el fichero `functions.php` del tema añadiendo algo como esto:

```
function incluir-javascripts()
{  
    wp_register_script( 'hliveFlashEmbed', '/resources/scripts/hliveFlashEmbed.js',array( 'jquery' ) ); 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'hliveFlashEmbed' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'incluir-javascripts' );
```

Hay que registrar el script y luego añadirlo a la cola, para que wordpress lo cargue.

La función `add_action` usa el Hook `wp_enqueue_scripts` el cual ejecutará la función `incluir-javascripts`

La función `wp_register_script` sirve para registrar el script. y admite varios parámetros. [Aquí](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/) más información sobre los parámetros que admite.

La función `wp_enqueue_script` sirve para poner en cola el script.